# Unable to update column in sqlite

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, ipad, sqlite

I am developing app, in which i am storing data in DB,

While storing data to DB, I am unable to update my column value in DB,

**Here is my Code:**

I am passing my Update query to this method:

```
QUERY = UPDATE Tbl SET favStatus ='0' WHERE Merchant_ID='1522' and Voucher_Id='5038'
```

//Calling method..

**[self UpdateStatus:QUERY];**

```
-(void)UpdateStatus:(NSString*)Query{

    // Get the documents directory
    databasePath=[self GetDBPath];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, [Query UTF8String],-1,&compiledStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Successful update");
        }
        sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

My Tbl contains `Col1`,`Col2`,`Col3`,`Col4`,`favStatus`,`Col6` 6 columns, i want to update value inside `favStatus` column.

After writing this, `favStatus` column value doesn't get updated even after Log shows `Successful update`

Where is my mistake? please help.

**Thanks in advnace.**

Comment: Maybe it is already the desired value.

Comment: Desired value is '1' ii want to change it to '0'

Comment: Do you need to commit the data ? ("BEGIN TRANSACTION/END TRANSACTION" in SQLite parlance I think....)

Comment: yes i want to commit the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check, please the col named `favStatus` is `bool` type or string type defined in your DB. If you enter string value on db , but column `fvStatus` is `bool` type. and you enter VoucherId and merchant ID value as a string. Please check both the value in DB as a string or not.

Can you share your Tb1 Schema structure.

Updated:

```
//
//  VMViewController.m
//  iDev_Sqlite
//
//  Created by Pathik on 3/14/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Pathik. All rights reserved.
//

#import "VMViewController.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface VMViewController ()
{
    sqlite3     *sqliteObj;
    NSString    *databasePath;
}
@end

@implementation VMViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self createDatabase];
   [self insertValuesInTable];

    [self updateValuesInTable];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - SQLITE Actions

-(void)createDatabase{

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"VM_TEST_DB.sqlite"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sqliteObj) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, favStatus INTEGER, Voucher_ID TEXT, Merchent_ID TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(sqliteObj, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }

            sqlite3_close(sqliteObj);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
}




-(void)insertValuesInTable{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sqliteObj) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO tbl1 (favStatus,Voucher_ID,Merchent_ID) VALUES (0,'102','102')"];

        const char*insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteObj, insert_stmt,  -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Insert Successfully||");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"INSERT OPERTAION FALIED||");
        }


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(sqliteObj);
    }
}

-(void)updateValuesInTable{

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqliteObj) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE tbl1 SET favStatus=1 WHERE Voucher_ID='101' AND Merchent_ID='101';"];
        const char * sql = [cmd UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteObj, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_step(compiledStatement); // Here is the added step.
            NSLog(@"update SUCCESS - executed command %@",cmd);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"update FAILED - failed to execute command %@",cmd);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@" FAILED - failed to open database");
    }

    sqlite3_close(sqliteObj);


}


![output][1]
@end


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0RTU.png
```

Comment: favStatus column is integer type, `VoucherId` and `merchant ID` are string type

Comment: Please refer new comment.

Comment: Update one is working code for your reference, please check it, if you have any issue, let me know.

Comment: I have accepted your answer also up voted plz upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the column named `favStatus` is `bool` type or string type defined in your DB.

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);

if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
           ///successful 
} 
else 
{
          ///Unsuccessful 
}
```

Try this in your code ...

Comment: favStatus column is integer type